# Keras - Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm attempting to train a neural network to evaluate chess positions. I have around 100 CSV files each with about 10,000 positions, leading to roughly 1,000,000 positions in total. Because of the large dataset size, I am using generators to train the network. I am representing the input to the network as a vector of size 768. Here is the training code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train_directory = '...'
test_directory = '...'

def generate_batches(file_list, batch_size, file_directory):
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        file = file_list[cnt]
        cnt = (cnt + 1) % len(file_list)
        data = pd.read_csv(file_directory + file)

        x = np.array(data['Positions'])
        Y = np.array(data['Evaluations'])

        X = []

        for pos in x:
            curr = []
            for num in pos:
                if(num == '-1'):
                    curr.append(-1)
                elif(num == '1'):
                    curr.append(1)
                elif(num == '0'):
                    curr.append(0)
            X.append(curr)

        X = np.array(X)

        for idx in range(0, X.shape[0], batch_size):
            X_loc = X[idx:(idx + batch_size)]
            Y_loc = Y[idx:(idx + batch_size)]
            
            yield X_loc, Y_loc




train_filenames = []
for file in os.listdir(train_directory):
    if(file.endswith('.csv')):
        train_filenames.append(file)

test_filenames = []
for file in os.listdir(test_directory):
    if(file.endswith('.csv')):
        test_filenames.append(file)


train_generator = generate_batches(train_filenames, 10000, train_directory)
test_generator = generate_batches(test_filenames, 10000, test_directory)


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, input_shape=(768,), activation='elu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='elu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='elu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.7, nesterov=True)
stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30)
save = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.h5', save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
model.load_weights('weights.h5')
model.fit(steps_per_epoch=len(train_filenames), workers=1, x=train_generator, max_queue_size=32, epochs=100000, callbacks=[stop, save], validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=len(test_filenames), batch_size=256)

model.save_weights('weights.h5')
```

I'm running into a weird issue with the training - it works fine for exactly 36 epochs. The loss goes down, albeit rather slowly, but after 36 epochs the program crashes with the following error:

```
 W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
 [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

I've seen others with the same question and same error, but none of their solutions fixed my issue. Does anyone know how to approach this?